# How to left_join multiple data frames with same dimensions without increasing row numbers?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have a few data frames that have the same columns # and row #. Only difference between dataframes is for certain columns, there are values that other dataframes do not have. Think of my goal as to take multiple parchment papers with a map and when you hold them together and look at it through light, you see the secret treasure marked X.

The dataframes I have are pretty large for me to replicate here, but I'll give an example case.

```
    DF1 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), Coordinates=c("100", "200","300","400","500"),Var1=c(NA,"20",NA,NA,"9"), Var2=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), Var3=c(NA, NA,NA,NA,NA))

    DF2 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), Coordinates=c("100", "200","300","400","500"), Var1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), Var2=c("0",NA,"20",NA,"0"), Var3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)) 

    DF3 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), Coordinates=c("100", "200","300","400","500"), Var1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), Var2=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), Var3=c(NA,"30",NA,NA,"50"))
```

As you can see, each data frame has one unique "Var" column and the other two don't contain anything.

I want the following outcome:
DF4

| ID | Coordinates | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | NA | 0 | 30 |
| B | 200 | 20 | NA | NA |
| C | 300 | NA | 20 | NA |
| D | 400 | NA | NA | NA |
| E | 500 | 9 | 0 | 50 |

What have I done so far?

```
DF4 <- DF1 %>% full_join(DF2,by=c("ID","Coordinates"))
DF4 <- DF4 %>% full_join(DF3,by=c("ID","Coordinates"))
```

This almost triples the number of lines in my DF4. So I resorted to left_join.

```
DF4 <- DF1 %>% left_join(DF2,by=c("ID","Coordinates"))
DF4 <- DF4 %>% left_join(DF3,by=c("ID","Coordinates"))
```

This time its not as bad, but still nrow(DF4) =/= nrow(DF1) = nrow(DF2) = nrow(DF3).

What I don't understand is how does my nrow(DF4) increase when im left_joining by same columns. I know if left DF has multiple mappings in right DF, the number of rows can increase but it isn't the case with my dataframes. Can anyone suggest why or a better way to handle this?

Comment: The number of rows increases when either **(a)** there are values in your `by` columns in one data frame but not in the other (using `left_join` instead of `full_join` will solve this) or **(b)** there are duplicate values in your `by` columns resulting in multiple matches. For example if `DF1` has 2 rows with `ID = A` and `DF2` has 2 rows with `ID = A`, then the result will have 2*2 = 4 rows with `ID = A`.

Comment: To "fix" (b), you either need to de-duplicate the `by` columns from your data frames so that there are not multiples, or (usually better if you can) add more columns to `by` so that each row is uniquely identified by values in the `by` column.

Comment: That said, for your use case of filling in `NA` values, you may want to use `rows_patch()` instead. I believe `rows_patch` will give you errors if there are multiple matches.

Comment: *"I know if left DF has multiple mappings in right DF, the number of rows can increase but it isn't the case with my dataframes."* I would gladly bet that this is indeed the case for your real data. (It's not the case in your sample data, and your sample data doesn't demonstrate the problem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we need to make the columns have the same type. Your DF2$Var1, for instance, is type `logical` when loaded.

Once that's consistent, `dplyr::rows_patch` offers a nice syntax to collate non-NA's from multiple source tables.

```
char <- function(df) df |>  mutate(across(3:5, as.character)) 

char(DF1) |>
  dplyr::rows_patch(char(DF2)) |>
  dplyr::rows_patch(char(DF3))
```

Result

```
Matching, by = "ID"
Matching, by = "ID"
  ID Coordinates Var1 Var2 Var3
1  A         100 <NA>    0 <NA>
2  B         200   20 <NA>   30
3  C         300 <NA>   20 <NA>
4  D         400 <NA> <NA> <NA>
5  E         500    9    0   50
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it with `summarise` and `across`:

```
library(dplyr) #> 1.1.0

bind_rows(DF1, DF2, DF3) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("Var"), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.)), NA, max(na.omit(.)))), .by=c(ID, Coordinates))

  ID Coordinates Var1 Var2 Var3
1  A         100 <NA>    0 <NA>
2  B         200   20 <NA>   30
3  C         300 <NA>   20 <NA>
4  D         400 <NA> <NA> <NA>
5  E         500    9    0   50
```

Comment: This seems like it will work. If my variables have different names instead of Var, how can I modify the "starts_with" portion of your code?

Comment: Instead of `starts_with(....` use `-c(ID, Coordinates)`